# pandas groupby aggregate specific columns by sum and other columns by most common value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
road    dirn    length  lane
1        L         0     2
1        L       0.6     2
1        L       1.2     1
1        L       0.8     2
2        R       1.5     3
2        R       0.4     2
2        R         9     3
```

I need to aggregate this dataframe where I will groupby the  columns 'road' and 'dirn', and sum on column 'length' and get the most common value from column 'lanes'. The resultant dataframe should look like:

```
road    dirn    length  lanes
1        L       2.6     2
1        L      10.9     3
```

I can do the groupby and sum easily using groupby, agg and sum. I have seen that most common value can be obtained using value_counts, but I am not sure how to combine both sum and value_counts. The actual dataframe is quite large and I might need to apply the sum and value counts to multiple columns.

Can someone please help me understand:
i) how to groupby and get sum for 'length' and most common value for 'lanes'
ii) how to expand that to groupby (multiple columns), sum multiple columns), most common value (renaming columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `sum` and for most common value is used [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['road','dirn'], as_index=False)
         .agg({'length':'sum','lane':lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]}))
```

Similar idea with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['road','dirn'], as_index=False)
         .agg({'length':'sum','lane':lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]}))
```

---

```
print (df1)
   road dirn  length  lane
0     1    L     2.6     2
1     2    R    10.9     3
```

EDIT: If there is list of columns names for both aggregate function is possible use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with dictionary merged by `**`:

```
sumL = ['length', 'accidents']
modeL = ['lane']

func = lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]

d = {**dict.fromkeys(sumL, 'sum'), **dict.fromkeys(modeL, func)}
print (d)

df1 = df.groupby(['road','dirn'], as_index=False).agg(d)
```

Comment: Dont think you need ``iat`` for mode : ``df.groupby(["road", "dirn"], as_index=False).agg(
    {"length": "sum", "lane": lambda x: x.mode()}
)`` seems to work fine

Comment: @sammywemmy - ya, `iat` is if possible multiple most common values, then it return first value.

Comment: @sammywemmy - it is possible test if change first `2` to `1`, if no `iat` it failed by `ValueError: Function does not reduce`

Comment: @jezrael both of them work! thank you very much. Can you also tell me how can I pass a list of olumns instead of a single column for both the sum and the mode/value_counts functions? My dataframe has over 70 columns.

Comment: @alak025 - hmmm, can you be more specific about columns names? There is list of columns names for `sum` and list for `mode` ?

Comment: @jezrael yes that is right. For example I have the following columns to sum - length, accidents, intersections and for mode - lanes, road shoulder, road lighting etc.I have data for these columns for multiple years, hence about 70 columns.

Comment: @jezrael this works beautifully! thank you again. I am curious about one thing - if value_counts finds the same frequency for more than one value in that column, which one does it choose as the most common value?

Comment: @alak025 - Not 100% sure, but seems first sorted value.

Answer (score 0):

Code below would give sum of column `length` and provide `mode` of column `lane`

```
df.groupby(['road','dirn']).agg({'length':[np.sum],'lane':[pd.Series.mode]})
```

Below code would sum column `length` and provide max of column `lane`

```
df.groupby(['road','dirn']).agg({'length':[np.sum],'lane':[np.max]}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. The solutions work. However I can now see that this will work for numeric data. Unfortunately I do have some descriptive string data as well. For such cases the value_counts is working as expected.